# Can I make changes directly in a WordPress live site or should I do it in staging first then make it live?

Tags: wordpress

I want some suggestions from you, I am creating some WordPress websites and I am making changes directly in live websites, I have read at some places that we should not make changes to live website we should prefer to create staging site first then make change in staging environment and then sync it with live website.

If I should follow this method then how can I create a staging site of my website and how can I sync the changes of staging site with my live website?

How can I do this?

Suggestions and some tool to create staging WordPress sites of my live site.